# window.scrollTo(x, y) is not working in mobile iOS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scrollto

Trying to create a website that can

1. move screen to the RIGHT while scrolling UP
2. move screen to the LEFT while scrolling DOWN

I used the function of `window.scrollTo` for moving the screen. It works perfect in decktop browser and the desktop Chrome's mobile view. But, the function is not working in mobile even iOS Safari or iOS Chrome. Tried the [`setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11865016/5737856), but still not work. Any suggestions?

Below is the simplified codes that has the same issue.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"> <!-- disable desktop scrolling -->
    <img style="width: 300%;" src="https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Mobile
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ 
        handleTouchMove(e);
        
        e.preventDefault(); // disable mobile user interaction
    }, { passive: false });

    var currentX = 0;

    function scrolling(isUp) {
        var movingBy = 10;
        // backward
        if (isUp) {
            currentX -= Math.min(movingBy, currentX);
        // forward
        } else {
            currentX += Math.min(movingBy, $(window).width() * 2 - currentX);
        }
        window.scrollTo(currentX, 0);
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);  

    var xDown = null;                                                        
    var yDown = null;                                               
                                                                             
    function handleTouchStart(evt) {
        var touches = evt.touches || evt.originalEvent.touches;
        const firstTouch = touches[0];                                      
        xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
        yDown = firstTouch.clientY;                                      
    };                                                
                                                                             
    function handleTouchMove(evt) {
        var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
        var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

        var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
        var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
                                                                             
        if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {     
            // left and right            
        } else {
            // up and down
            scrolling(yDiff <= 0);                                                           
        }

        xDown = xUp;
        yDown = yUp;                                             
    };

    // desktop
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: This slightly different thread might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397097/19162438

Answer (score 0):

## possible solution

although it is not certain if this is the real reason, code in the question is missing a following part that is necessary for iOS screen size calculation.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
```

related SO answer: [$(window).width() returning same value in portrait/landscape mode of iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303041/window-width-returning-same-value-in-portrait-landscape-mode-of-iphone)

Comment: Tried, but still cannot scroll

Comment: @PakHoCheung I've tried to reproduce the bug on CodePen with my iPhone 13 + iOS chrome, safari and it all works fine. https://codepen.io/rabelais88/pen/dyjpWxY could you reproduce the bug that you're experiencing?

Comment: I uploaded the code here. ```https://test12ds3fe33.000webhostapp.com/test.html``` Would you mind to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

It's your overflow. I removed overflow:hidden and tested it on an ios device and it worked fine. Just remove that line and you'll be good. May need to play with hiding just x or y overflow depending on what you're looking for.

EDIT: If you are wanting to prevent default scrolling and only allow scrolling from js you might look at this post -> [Overflow-x:hidden doesn't prevent content from overflowing in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0px; height: 100%;"> <!-- disable desktop scrolling -->
    <img style="width: 300%;" src="https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Mobile
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); // disable mobile user interaction
        handleTouchMove(e);
        
        
    }, { passive: false });

    var currentX = 0;

    function scrolling(isUp) {
        var movingBy = 10;
        // backward
        if (isUp) {
            currentX -= Math.min(movingBy, currentX);
        // forward
        } else {
            currentX += Math.min(movingBy, $(window).width() * 2 - currentX);
        }

        window.scrollTo(currentX, 0);
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);  

    var xDown = null;                                                        
    var yDown = null;                                               
                                                                             
    function handleTouchStart(evt) {
        var touches = evt.touches || evt.originalEvent.touches;
        const firstTouch = touches[0];                                      
        xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
        yDown = firstTouch.clientY;      
    };                                                
                                                                             
    function handleTouchMove(evt) {
        var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
        var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

        var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
        var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
                                                                             
        if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {     
            // left and right            
        } else {
            // up and down
            scrolling(yDiff <= 0);                                                           
        }

        xDown = xUp;
        yDown = yUp;                                             
    };
</script>
```